# Add-ADGroupMember Limitation

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that is adding members to a group

$ADUsers = Import-csv c:\test.csv
$Username     = $ADUsers.username

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity (Get-ADGroup "testing") -Members $Username -Confirm:$false
[$Username is an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZBqo.png)

And I get the error:
"Error occured in AddADGroupMembers Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running."

The script is working with 10k users but getting error when I'm trying to add 20k users. I want to know the limitations of Add-ADGroupMember.

Comment: So you are running this line of code 20000 times?

Comment: No, $Username is an array, I have added a snip below https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9bIJ.png

Answer (score 1):

I could not find anything about he maximum number of users you can use in one `Add-ADGroupMember` call, but since the maximum for `Get-ADGroupMember` by default is set to 5000 (see [MaxGroupOrMemberEntries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd391908(v=ws.10))) in AD, I would not go beyond this number.

You should break up the array of users to add into multiple chunks.
Try something like this:

```
# get an array of usernames to add to the group from the CSV
$ADUsers = (Import-Csv -Path 'c:\test.csv').username
$GroupDN = (Get-ADGroup -Identity 'testing').DistinguishedName
# set your maximum for the number of users to add in each iteration
$chunkSize  = 4000  # use trial and error on this, but stay on the safe side
$maxItems   =  $ADUsers.Count
$iterations = [Math]::Ceiling($maxItems / $chunkSize)

for ($i = 1; $i -le $iterations; $i++) {
    $firstItem = (($i - 1) * $chunkSize)
    $lastItem  = [Math]::Min(($i * $chunkSize) - 1, $maxItems - 1)
    $userToAdd = $ADUsers[$firstItem..$lastItem]
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupDN -Members $userToAdd -Confirm:$false 
}
```